# window too big, can't resize or maximize

Tags: window

I'm running Kate under Gnome. Somehow it was resized to a too-large size for my desktop. So now the Maximize and Resize buttons are unreachable. I'm assuming reinstalling would fix the problem, but if I can fix it without reinstalling that would be ideal. Any ideas/suggestions are much appreciated. (I have tried the keyboard shortcuts, with no results.)

[image]

Comment: Can't you just grab the windows top and drag it to the left part of the screen (again and again) until you reach for the right part of the window?

Comment: No, that didn't work either, but I figured it out! Turns out the *session* was corrupt. When I started a brand new session, I got everything back.

Comment: Solution here might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/96375/why-are-my-file-selection-dialogs-so-big-how-do-i-make-them-smaller

Answer (score 54):

When a window is bigger than the resolution of the monitor do the following:

1. Press and HOLD <kbd>ALT</kbd> (On Ubuntu 18.04+ Hold <kbd>SUPER</kbd>) and then simply click and HOLD the mouse button over the window you want.
2. Start dragging it until you can see the top part or at least a corner to resize it. Keep holding the corresponding key while doing each click until you can see a corner or the top. From there just resize it as you like.

Comment: THANK YOU! Accidentally resized a window larger than the screen.

Comment: In my case (ubuntu 18.04, dell laptop), the alt key must be replaced by the home key.

Comment: I'm glad I found this. The window problem is so annoying!

Comment: This doesn't help, holding alt gives nothing on lastest ubuntu 18.

Comment: @stiv It was changed to SUPER.

Comment: I don't have SUPER key on my keyboard.

Comment: @stiv You don't have the key that has a windows logo in it? It's the same one you would use to open the search box on gnome.

Comment: This works on raspbian 10 buster - which is a huge help since you often have tiny screens with a RaspberryPi!

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.04 with Super (windows) key. To make it clearer: you can click and hold at parts of the window *other than the title bar*, so a part outside the screen on lower edge can be brought up by holding super key, clicking the middle of the window and dragging upwards

Comment: This is still relevant for 2023 and Lunar Lobster (Ubuntu 23.04) / Gnome 44.0. Thank you!

Answer (score 21):

Try this:
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>
and then you can move the window, so you can reach the button :)

Comment: Thanks! I did try that, with no luck. (Alt+f7 works to move other windows, but not the messed up Kate window.)

Comment: This works on Fedora

Comment: this answer is more relevant now that in ubuntu 18.04 alt no longer grabs window

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04 in Unity. I solved it by deleting all of the config files for kate. I found them under home/USERNAME/.kde/share/config.

WARNING: this will also remove any custom highlighting, colors, etc. when you do this.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a bit detailed version of `Ffoeg311`'s.

Just rename the file `kritarc`(something like kritarc.old or kritarc.backup or may be anything) or delete the file `kritarc` which is in the path `/home/USERNAME/.kde/share/config/`. You can leave the remaining files.

Answer (score 1):

You simplify use shortcut for GNOME window <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> in order to move it freely. Then, focusing on your factor and rescaling it.

Or in the tweak-tool window, click the magnifier icon (search option), then enter *scaling* in the text field. That will display only options for which the name matches the word *scaling*. Now click the entry Windows. The option Window Scaling will now be located up the content pane and you could edit it back to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not in fullscreen mode?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> should toggle it on and off.

Answer (score 0):

My whole screen shifted to the right by 75% or so.  I couldn't reach the up/down or left/right bars, so I tried what I thought was moving the screen to the left.  I ended up resizing it, so then it was left adjusted, but the text still started 3/4 of the way to the right.  After playing with it a while, I found if I went to the work space switcher and selected the space my file was spilling over into, I could 'pull' the page back into place by resizing it back where it belonged.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it. In the main window (Anaconda):

1. Click **Files**
2. Click **Preferences**
3. Uncheck *Enable high DPI scaling*, then click <kbd>Apply</kbd>.
4. Restart Anaconda (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck with a tiny screen with low resolution on some non-standard device that is not hardware-capable of fitting more pixels, and you need to press e.g. an <kbd>Ok</kbd> button that is off-screen, then you might still use the keyboard to repeatedly press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to switch the focus to the unreachable button and then press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Might require a bit of guessing about how many times you need to press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.