# Gnome Shell - modal popups on dual screen systems

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, eclipse

I'm working on a laptop, which I connect to a second monitor if I'm at my desk. Everything works more or less well, but I'm having an issue with **modal popups**, especially in the Eclipse IDE - if used over two screens. Modal popups are **automatically centred** on the application window, and **can only be resized**, **but not moved** (use Window / Preferences as an example).

This makes it extremely hard and challenging to read the content of any application that stretches over two screens, especially if - as in my case - there is a gap of some centimetres between them. I definitely need a way to disable this behaviour...

Any hints?

Update: Uploaded a picture of my screens - I simply can't believe that I'm the only one with this issue...

[image: modal popups on dual screen systems in gnome3]

Comment: I have the same problem (it's constant across Openbox, Unity and GNOME Shell) but even offering a bounty didn't get it solved: http://askubuntu.com/questions/96375/why-are-my-file-selection-dialogs-so-big-how-do-i-make-them-smaller/

Comment: All right than, thanks for linking me to your issue. I will try to file a bug report - just wondering who would be responsible.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: I completely disagree with the closure. This is a problem all Gnome 3 users can have - no matter if it's caused by a bug. I slightly agreee that a reference to a bug report is a help for future readers - but I see absolutely no reason to consider this question off-topic.

Comment: @jangroth It is a bug, and *as such* is off-topic. http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-bugs. Bugs are off-topic here on Ask Ubuntu.